# Concatenate pandas column values based on common index

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Input dataframe

```
A      B
n1     "joe,jack"
n2     "kelly,john"
n3     "adam,sam"
n1     "jack,frank"
n3     "rita"
n4     "steve, buck"
n2     "john, kelly, peter"
```

Based on index `column A`, I want to concat text, seperated with `comma`(,). So the expected output would look like(any instance of repetition is taken only once)

```
A       B
n1      joe,jack,frank
n2      kelly,john,peter
n3      adam,sam,rita
n4      steve, buck
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with custom function with split, set comprehension and join if order is not important:

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(set([z for y in x for z in y.replace(', ',',').split(',')]))
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(f).reset_index()
print (df)
    A                 B
0  n1    jack,joe,frank
1  n2  john,kelly,peter
2  n3     adam,rita,sam
3  n4        steve,buck
```

If order is important for remove duplicated use `dict.fromkeys` trick:

```
f = lambda x:','.join(dict.fromkeys([z for y in x for z in y.replace(', ',',').split(',')]))
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(f).reset_index()
print (df)
    A                 B
0  n1    joe,jack,frank
1  n2  kelly,john,peter
2  n3     adam,sam,rita
3  n4        steve,buck
```